# AKS node not showing up in kubectl get nodes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-container-service

I added a node to an AKS cluster. After 40 minutes the operation failed without any other details. Then I added some more nodes, and this time the operation succeeded.

However, I still can't see the nodes in the Kubernetes Dashboard or with `kubectl get nodes`.

I currently have no way to address the memory issue in my cluster since I can't seem to add more nodes.

Answer (score 0):

How do scale AKS nodes? Via Azure portal or CLI?

You can use this command to scale aks nodes:

`az aks scale --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup --node-count 3`

After you scale AKS nodes, you should wait for sometime and re-run this command `az aks get-credentials`,  then use `kubectl get nodes` to get the informations.

Comment: I scaled it in the portal. It also said there that it failed. Do you know why I should re-run the `az aks get-credentials` command?

Comment: @SebastianRösch Sorry for the delay, could you please show me that error message?

Comment: @SebastianRösch Can you scale your AKS now? please let me know if you need more help.